# Multiple $_GET handling

Tags: php, html, get, request

So I have different buttons that call get requests, but only one is working, when they are called, they are called by act and act2, act is working fine, but act2 does nothing when called, can someone help? Ive tried tweaking the names, changing database settings, nothing seems to work for me right now.

this is how the get is called:

```
<center><a href="?p=attempt&id='.$row['id'].'&act=delete" title="Delete log"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a> <a href="?p=attempt&ip='.$row['ip'].'&act=blacklist" title="Blacklist IP"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></a></center>'
```

this is the responses

```
if (isset($_GET['act2']))
                    {
                        if (!isset($_GET['ip']))
                        {
                            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">No log ID.  </div><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=?p=settings">';
                        }else{
                            $act = $_GET['act2'];
                            $tid = $_GET['ip'];
                            if (ctype_digit($tid))
                            {
                                if (ctype_alnum($act))
                                {
                                    $arr = array('blacklist');
                                    if (in_array($act, $arr))
                                    {
                                        $cnt = $odb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM login_attempts WHERE id = :i");
                                        $cnt->execute(array(":i" => $tid));
                                        if ($cnt->fetchColumn(0) > 0)
                                        {


                                            $cpermss = $odb->prepare("SELECT privileges FROM users WHERE username = :u");
                                            $cpermss->execute(array(":u" => $_SESSION['username']) );
                                            $cperms = $cpermss->fetchColumn(0);
                                            if ($userperms == "moderator" && $cperms == "admin")
                                            {
                                                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Invalid Permissions.</div>';
                                            }else{
                                                if ($userperms == "user" && strtolower($cr) != strtolower($username))
                                                {
                                                    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Invalid Permissions.</div>';
                                                }else{
                                                    switch ($act)
                                                    {
                                                        case "blacklist":
                                                            $de = $odb->prepare("INSERT INTO 'blacklist'(ip) VALUES [':i']");
                                                            $de->execute(array(":i" => $tid));
                                                            echo '<div class="alert alert-success">ip added to blacklist.  </div><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=settings.php">';
                                                            break;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }else{
                                            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Log not found in database.  </div><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=?p=settings">';
                                        }
                                    }else{
                                        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Invalid action.  </div><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=?p=settings">';
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }





if (isset($_GET['act']))
                    {
                        if (!isset($_GET['id']))
                        {
                            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">No log ID.  </div><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=?p=settings">';
                        }else{
                            $act = $_GET['act'];
                            $tid = $_GET['id'];
                            if (ctype_digit($tid))
                            {
                                if (ctype_alnum($act))
                                {
                                    $arr = array('delete');
                                    if (in_array($act, $arr))
                                    {
                                        $cnt = $odb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM login_attempts WHERE id = :i");
                                        $cnt->execute(array(":i" => $tid));
                                        if ($cnt->fetchColumn(0) > 0)
                                        {


                                            $cpermss = $odb->prepare("SELECT privileges FROM users WHERE username = :u");
                                            $cpermss->execute(array(":u" => $_SESSION['username']) );
                                            $cperms = $cpermss->fetchColumn(0);
                                            if ($userperms == "moderator" && $cperms == "admin")
                                            {
                                                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Invalid Permissions.</div>';
                                            }else{
                                                if ($userperms == "user" && strtolower($cr) != strtolower($username))
                                                {
                                                    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Invalid Permissions.</div>';
                                                }else{
                                                    switch ($act)
                                                    {
                                                        case "delete":
                                                            $de = $odb->prepare("DELETE FROM login_attempts WHERE id = :i");
                                                            $de->execute(array(":i" => $tid));
                                                            echo '<div class="alert alert-success">log deleted.  </div><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=settings.php">';
                                                            break;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }else{
                                            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Log not found in database.  </div><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=?p=settings">';
                                        }
                                    }else{
                                        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Invalid action.  </div><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=?p=settings">';
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: I see no references to `act2` anywhere.

Comment: so this is the code with `act` only. Please also add code with `act2` in it so we can actually see why it is not working.

Comment: my bad, ive updated the code with the rest

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if im wrong but your HTML is still appending the parameter 'act' not 'act2'

```
href="?p=attempt&id='.$row['id'].'&act=delete"
```

Your ISSET on the GET superglobal variable return false and not perform any action.

What exactly is the purpose of having act and act2? are you trying to perform 2 delete functions at the same time?

Comment: there are two different buttons, one that i want to add the ip to a table in a database, then another that deletes it from the current table, act, is the delete, act2 is the moving of the table. So im trying to figure out why the &act=delete works, but &act2=blacklist doesnt

Comment: Where is act2=blacklist in what you posted? In your original post you have `&act=blacklist" title="Blacklist IP"` not act2. Was/is that simply a typo?

Comment: I think it was a typo, i was trying to fix the error so i was testing out different things